# htaccess is not working at xampp but not at hosting server

Tags: php, apache

I have a .htaccess code for

```
www.site.com/article.php?param1=val&param2=val&param3=val
```

It's working at xampp localhost but not working at PHP hosting:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/icons
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) article.php?x=$1&y=$2&article_id=$3 [NC]
```

When i use this on hosting its saying:

```
this page is not working(500)
```

Comment: İ have found that   its not working becouse of underscores at parameter names (article_id) but if you have any suggestion you can help. thank you soo much

Comment: is your apache has enabled mod_rewrite?

Comment: You get a 500 error, so you need to go check the server’s error log to find out what caused it. Go check if you have access to the error log with your hosting platform; if not, ask their support to check it for you.

Comment: thank you soo much friends i have  realize i didnt upload to new functions.php file. there was missing function in page and also it was giving error becouse of underscore at parameter name like i said. once i solve the problem do i need to close this page or do something else ?